# Newey West standard errors in regression model without constant

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, intercept, neweywest

I'm estimating $y_i= \beta_1 \times x_{1i} + \varepsilon_i$ on a time series on $y$ and $x$, so in presence of heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation. My model does not include any intercepts. Are Newey West standard errors calculated on such model appropriate (in other words, the NW correction requires a full model with intercept)? I am using R sandwich and `lmtest` packages.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two screenshots (if that is not OK I hope moderators will let me know) of the papers by [Newey and West (Review of Economic Studies 1994)](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~kwest/publications/1990/Automatic%20Lag%20Selection%20in%20Covariance%20Matrix%20Estimation.pdf) and [Andrews (Econometrica 1991)](http://www.utdallas.edu/~d.sul/Econo2/andrews91.pdf), which are follow up papers to the more high-level Newey/West paper:

[image]

Andrews:

[image]

As you can see, having constant plays no role. What matters is that the coefficient estimates for which you want autocorrelation-robust standard errors are themselves ($\sqrt{T}$-)consistently estimated, so, more or less, that they are computed from a correctly specified model.

Now, if your model is such that it indeed does not need a constant (which may happen), that should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, Christoph, I agree. The input that the sandwich package needs are the scores for a model with the "usual" central limit theorem, i.e., , consistency and asymptotic normality at rate sqrt(n). The scores are just the observation-wise contributions to the gradient (first-order condition). All of this also applies to linear models without constant so I wouldn't see any potential problems.