# Robust regression for autocorrelation and heteroskedasticity - coefficients do not change, only standard errors change?

Tags: least-squares, robust-standard-error

When using Newey-West robust standard errors to deal with heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation:

http://support.sas.com/kb/40/098.html

is it correct to state that the coefficients are not different between a robust and a non-robust estimation? Only the standard errors change, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, as the name suggests, only the standard errors change.

Comment: Thanks Christoph for confirming this. Some reference would also be nice, thanks.

Comment: See, e.g., the textbooks by Stock and Watson or Hayashi. Also, here are a couple of threads on CV which should be relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353922/eicker-huber-white-robust-variance-estimator https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/139614/robust-ols-standard-errors-newey-west https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142289/newey-west-standard-errors-in-regression-model-without-constant https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/286894/difference-between-hccme-and-wls-estimator/287122#287122

Comment: Many thanks Christoph, very helpful.